# Any risks to casting an object in Swift as a less specific protocol?

Tags: ios, swift

In the example below, is it reasonable to make `TextViewController` conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate` instead of `UITextViewDelegate` and then cast the text view as a scroll view (or maybe declare it as a `UIScrollView`)? If not how would you suggest doing this?

I don't want to make the code look like `TextViewController` could conform to `UITextViewDelegate` because that would be confusing. I assume that the cast would fail if a non-optional method were added to `UITextViewDelegate`. Also, private/fileprivate extensions are not allowed, but that would reduce my concern.

```swift
class TextViewController: UIViewController {

    let textView = UITextView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        textView.delegate = self // Error
        (textView as? UIScrollView)?.delegate = self // OK
    }
}

extension TextViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate
{

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        doSomethingOnScroll()
    }
}
```

```swift
extension UIScrollViewDelegate where Self: UIViewController {

    func doSomethingOnScroll() {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

I did not create my own protocol in this example to make the code more concise.

Comment: Without getting into why you don't declare conformance to `UITextViewDelegate` and why you want just `UIScrollViewDelegate`, I think you've already covered the risk - if the more specific protocol has any non-optional methods, you can't just conform to the less specific protocol. Since `UITextViewDelegate` has no non-optional methods, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Adding an answer because this is too long for comments.)

To add some more explicit detail about *why* what you're doing is a bad idea:

The situation you're encountering here is an Objective-C-ism that normally isn't allowed in Swift; specifically, you're dealing here with a property on a subtype (`UITextView : UIScrollView`) that is more specific than its supertype's property (`UITextViewDelegate : UIScrollViewDelegate`). This violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), but Objective-C's type system is [weak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) enough to happily allow this.

You already implicitly call this out, but briefly for readers: `UIScrollView`'s `delegate` property allows *any* `UIScrollViewDelegate`-conforming object to be assigned to it; after all, anything that conforms to the protocol will satisfy `UIScrollView`'s need for information about how to handle events. `UITextView`, however, overrides this property, accepting *only* objects which conform to the more specific `UITextViewDelegate` protocol, since it has more questions to ask the delegate about how to handle various scenarios. Under normal subtyping rules (and when the Liskov substitution principle holds), if you take an object `a: A`, and cast it to its superclass `B`, all of its properties should hold exactly as they were... except this is not true for `UITextView`. When you cast an instance of `UITextView` to `UIScrollView`, its `delegate` property suddenly becomes *more general*, meaning that you can assign a `UIScrollViewDelegate` which is *not* a `UITextViewDelegate` to the `delegate` property (since, again, `UIScrollView` only cares about things that `UIScrollViewDelegate` can tell it). If `UITextViewDelegate` had required methods, this would be immediately problematic, because at *runtime*, the text view would attempt to call a method on the delegate that it doesn't know how to answer.

You mention that

> I assume that the cast would fail if a non-optional method were added to UITextViewDelegate

but it's important to stress that this is **not** true. `UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, and so `textView as? UIScrollView` will *unconditionally* succeed — it simply maintains Objective-C's behavior when accessing the properties on the supertype, as if they were statically-typed properties. What this means is that `(textView as? UIScrollView)?.delegate` will *always* allow you to assign a `UIScrollViewDelegate` object to the property, even if at runtime, `UITextView` will call methods on it that don't exist; although this can't reasonably happen (because existing delegate objects couldn't implicitly satisfy the requirement), if `UITextViewDelegate` did get non-optional method requirements, you would simply crash at runtime.

In your very specific case, this might work, but this is very unsafe to do in the general case.

---

For what it's worth, if you try to recreate this scenario in pure Swift, the compiler won't let you, for good reason:

```
protocol SuperDelegate {}
protocol SubDelegate: SuperDelegate {}

class SuperClass {
    var delegate: SuperDelegate?
}

class SubClass: SuperClass {
    override var delegate: SubDelegate?
    // ^ error: property 'delegate' with type '(any SubDelegate)?' cannot override a property with type '(any SuperDelegate)?'
}
```

Swift doesn't allow overriding properties with ones of different types *at all* to prevent this scenario, and similarly prevents inversions of method parameters and return values.

Comment: Thanks for the illuminating response. That explains why Swift never allows overriding properties with different types (not even when the classes and protocols are annotated as `@objc`, surprisingly).

Am I understanding the LSP violation correctly? `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` but what holds true for `UIScrollView.delegate` (namely, that it is a `UIScrollViewDelegate`) does not hold for the subclass: `UITextView.delegate` is not a `UIScrollViewDelegate`... even though `UITextViewDelegate` inherits from (**or is a subtype of?**) `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

Comment: Almost, but slightly inverted: all squares (`UITextViewDelegate`) are rectangles (`UIScrollViewDelegate`), but not all rectangles are squares: a rhombus (`UITableViewDelegate`) is a rectangle, but it is not a square. When a type declares that it can accept _any_ rectangle, if a subtype says "I only accept squares", then it doesn't uphold that property. If I upcast that subtype to the parent type, then hand it a rhombus, it'll blow up (even though the parent type says "I accept _all_ rectangles")

Comment: The ability of being able to validly upcast from one type to its parent is at odds with the ability of the subtype to place restrictions that the parent type doesn't have. You can't have both while still being consistent. (A post of mine that goes a bit more in depth on the Swift forums: https://forums.swift.org/t/typealias-conformance-to-protocols-why-cant-this-simple-thing-be-implemented/63302/58)

Comment: The fact that Swift allows this conditionally is confusing and not well documented so thanks for your explanation and link to your post, it's also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend this. It kind of works (though it throws a warning), but it's more confusing than what it replaces. TextViewController can definitely still implement UITextViewDelegate methods and they'll be called; they just have to be marked `@objc`. That's asking for subtle bugs as the code evolves. As others (or yourself, as you forgot that you did this), try to add UITextViewDelegate methods, they may or may not be called depending on how their added (in Swift or ObjC, or with or without the `@objc`). You can assume that'll never happen, but "this makes future bugs easier to create" is the risk.

It's not quite clear why you're trying to hide the conformance, but there are several ways to do so if it's important.

The most straightforward is to make `textView` itself a UIScrollView:

```
let _textView: UIScrollView = UITextView()
var textView: UITextView { _textView as! UITextView }

...

_textView.delegate = self
```

(If you made `textView` private and don't need UITextView access, this could be even simpler.)

Alternately, you can could create an internal private delegate for the UITextView so it's not exposed. It's not clear how exposing UITextViewDelegate matters more than exposing UIScrollViewDelegate. But if you want to hide these details, then I'd hide the whole thing in an internal type.

That said, your question was for advice. The advice is not to do this. If the question is "will this work," the answer is yes, except it throws a warning.